# How to export an Outlook calendar into an Excel weekly timesheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My boss has a calendar of meetings scheduled (of different projects) in Outlook.

How do I input the time spent on each project on each day in an Excel worksheet?

The Excel worksheet consists of all projects written in a column, and one column for each day of the week.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please edit your post to include any code or prove that you have do some research before asking something here!

Answer (score 10):

A simple google search, and a little refacto :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAppointments()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olApt As Object
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date

    FromDate = CDate("08/25/2017")
    ToDate = CDate("12/31/2017")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9) 'olFolderCalendar
    NextRow = 2

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of the sheet here
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Project", "Date", "Time spent", "Location")
        For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
            If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
                .Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End - olApt.Start
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
                .Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
                .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.Categories
                NextRow = NextRow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next olApt
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the Excel VBA code. I suggest to add two `Date` variables `FromDate` and `ToDate` to the code and `If (olApt.Start >= FromDate and olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then ...` to the `For` loop,  to restrict the amount of data exported to the relevant date range.

Comment: Another improvement: Add `.Cells(NextRow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS"` to the  `For` loop and it will correctly display the duration of each appointment.

Comment: @Matt : Thx for your input, I've edited the code! ;)

Comment: You're welcome, and btw. that was really worth a +1. I am using your code quite a lot now to export my appointments.

Comment: @Matt : Thx mate! Glad I could help! ;)

Comment: This is still working well in Office 2016! I've added this line:
`.Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.Categories` if you want to categorise your meetings for different projects etc.

Comment: @anyhotcountry : I've added it to my answer ;)

Comment: I don't see you set olApt to be defined as a type of object? I get compile error on If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) - its missing the "Then" at the end of the line

Comment: @AlGrant : Thx for pointing it out, my bad for the missing `Then` ! But I don't get your point about `Dim olApt As Object` ? Everything is declared as `Object` to use *Late Binding* and avoid compiler errors.