# Looping over recipients in a Outlook Appointments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752127/how-to-export-an-outlook-calendar-into-an-excel-weekly-timesheet/33752711#33752711) and trying to access the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia) (Email Address and also Display Name) of each Outlook Appointment but getting a Error:

> Run-time error '287' Application-defined or object-defined error

This error is highlighted on the line : For Each recip In olApt.recipients

```
Sub ListAppointments()
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim FromDate As Date
Dim ToDate As Date

FromDate = CDate("01/04/2019")
ToDate = CDate("14/04/2019")

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9) 'olFolderCalendar
NextRow = 2

With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of the sheet here
    .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Meeting", "Date", "Location", "Invitees")
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
            .Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
            .Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
            .Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.Location
            .Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Categories

            Dim recip As Object
            Dim allRecip As String
            For Each recip In olApt
                Debug.Print (recip.Address)
                .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.Address
            Next

            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next olApt
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

I tried

```
For Each recip in olApt.recipients
    .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.recipients.Address
Next
```

And I still get the errors below.

This is the error [image]

Here are two parts of the Watch on olApt

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

The answer works on my laptop but crashes on my desktop (seperate outlook account). This is the line it crashes on, and I not it wont let the "R" in recipients be a captial (it changes to lower case automatically despite typing a captial).

[image]

I also note that the Recipients collection on olApt is different on my laptop to my desktop:

[image]

Comment: Does this always happen wit ha particular appointment or only after processing a large number of appointments?

Comment: This is the first Appointment in that date range.

Comment: As guided by @DmitryStreblechenko Correct syntax and approach is to change to line

.`Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = recip.Address`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko may kindly put hisr answer guiding us about the mistake in line `.Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.recipients.Address`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I didn't - it was @skkakkar's answer and it was deleted by him. I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko any ideas on why it doesnt work on desktop? pls see update?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = olApt.recipients.Address
```

must be replaced with

```
.Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = recip.Address
```

Also keep in mind that Outlook Security can blocks access to properties such as `SenderEmailAddress` or `Recipients` if an antivirus app is not installed or is out of date. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model

Comment: I thought it was .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = recip.Address.Item(1)

Comment: No. Address is a string property. It does not expose Item method.  @skkakkar's (wrong) answer was to use "olApt.Recipients.Item(1)", but that always returns the first recipient (object, not a string). You already have the recipient object in the recip  variable from the "for each" loop. And your loop really needs to use separate cells, the existing code keeps writing multiple values to the same cell.

Comment: Thanks. The 287 error is still present on Desktop PC - see comment. The code is cut n paste the same.

Comment: Oh wait, do you have an AV app on the problematic machine?

Comment: Yes we have AV - the code does run fine pulling Subject Date and Location if I remove the Recipients loop. Also note in my pictures that Recipients <> collection is empty on Desktop PC.

Comment: Subject property is not blocked. Recipients is.

Comment: Are you saying some AV block, some dont, as both computers have AV.

Comment: That is not what I am saying at all. OOM blocks some sensitive properties if an AV app is not installed or is out of date.

Comment: For the sake of completeness do you want to add a reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model which explains the 287 error and I will mark the answer

Comment: Sure, see above.